# Execute a forEach like a waterfall in async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-api

I'm trying to retrieve longitude and latitude from a list of addresses with the Google API via a Node.js script. The call itself works fine but since I have around 100 addresses to submit. I use a `async.forEach` on an array, but the calls are made too fast and I get the error "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API."

I found that the number of calls is limited to 2500 every 24h and maximum 10 a second. While I'm OK for the 2500 a day, I make my calls way too fast for the rate limit.

I now have to write a function who will delay the calls enough not to reach the limit. Here is a sample of my code :

```
async.forEach(final_json, function(item, callback) {
    var path = '/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURIComponent(item.main_address)+'&sensor=false';
    console.log(path);
    var options = {
      host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
      port: 80,
      path: path,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    // a function I have who makes the http GET
    rest.getJSON(options, function(statusCode, res) {
      console.log(res);
      callback();
    });
}, function() {
  // do something once all the calls have been made
});
```

How would you proceed to achieve this? I tried putting my `rest.getJSON` inside a 100ms `setTimeout` but the `forEach` iterates through all the rows so fast that it starts all the `setTimeout` almost at the same time and therefore it doesn't change anything...

The `async.waterfall` looks like it would do the trick, but the thing is I don't know exactly how many rows I will have, so I can't hardcode all the function calls. And to be honest, it would make my code really ugly

Comment: Have you tried recursion? Use the callback to set a timeout to recursively call the fetch function after 100ms.

Comment: This seems like a generic enough problem that a general solution is appropriate.  Rate-limiting is a common construct and inline setTimeout hacks are probably not the right way to go.  Waterfall could be slower or faster than necessary, since all it does is wait for the last call to return.  If a call takes less than 1/10 of a second you're still too fast.

Comment: Why not something simple like `parallel` with 10 queued, when they're complete, make sure that a total of 10 seconds has passed before starting the next batch?

Comment: That's a neat version.  I was working on thinking through and coding up the loop w/125ms wait + a bucket for results not yet returned.  The loop would place items in the bucket and the http callback would remove them.  Don't let the bucket become larger than 10, and don't push more than 8/second into the bucket.  When it's done and the bucket is empty (wait for it, wait for it...) execute your "all done function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you can create a `rateLimited` function that acts much like a `throttled` or `debounced` function, except any calls that don't execute immediately get queued and run in order as the rate limit time period expires.

Basically, it creates parallel 1 second intervals that self-manage via timer rescheduling, but only up to `perSecondLimit` intervals are allowed.

```
function rateLimit(perSecondLimit, fn) {
    var callsInLastSecond = 0;
    var queue = [];
    return function limited() {
        if(callsInLastSecond >= perSecondLimit) {
            queue.push([this,arguments]);
            return;
        }

        callsInLastSecond++;
        setTimeout(function() {
            callsInLastSecond--;
            var parms;
            if(parms = queue.shift()) {
                limited.apply(parms[0], parms[1]);
            }
        }, 1010);

        fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
function thisFunctionWillBeCalledTooFast() {}
var limitedVersion = rateLimit(10, thisFunctionWillBeCalledTooFast);

// 10 calls will be launched immediately, then as the timer expires
// for each of those calls a new call will be launched in it's place.
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    limitedVersion();
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful generic function! I took it as is, and it worked like a charm! Well, not exactly the first time, but instead of 10 I throttled it to 5 per second, and now it works (with 10 I would still get some errors, less with 9, but flawless with 5). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would hack it (Note: `arr` is your array of locations):

```
function populate(arr, callback, pos) {
    if(typeof pos == "undefined")
        pos=0;
    var path = '/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURIComponent(arr[pos].main_address)+'&sensor=false';
    console.log(path);
    var options = {
      host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
      port: 80,
      path: path,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    // a function I have who makes the http GET
    rest.getJSON(options, function(statusCode, res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
    pos++;

    if(pos<arr.length)
        setTimeout(function(){
            populate(arr,callback,pos);
        },110); //a little wiggle room since setTimeout isn't exact
    else
        callback();
}
```

You could add a rate limiting function, but, IMHO, it introduces unnecessary complexity. All you really want to do is call the function every tenth of a second or so until you're done with your list, so do that.

It's certainly not as extensible as the alternative, but I'm a fan of simplicity.

Comment: I tried to figure out how to do it with a recursive function but never came out with something functional. I didn't realize I had to remove completely the loop and emulate it myself! I still went with the generic function above, but yours is a good example of how to hack the problem with a recursive function!